# Article Show and Link to Article

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, menu, positions

I use the extension "Article Show" in Joomla 3
https://www.olwebdesign.com/joomla-extensions/article-show-joomla-module.html
I create a module "Last news" with the position "news" that is assigned in the Layout of my template.

https://www.vzw.ch/

In the module I specify that I want to see the instance of the module (a list of articles) in the Home menu (called VZW in my page).
[image: The list of news in the VZW menu]

When I click on a news, the corresponding article appears. But it is assigned to the same menu (either in the component area, or in a popup window). Since it is assigned to the same menu, the "Article show" list of news still appears under the individual article.
How to avoid that?

[image: The individual article with the list of news underneath]

Answer (score 0):

I want to publicly thank the developer Olwebdesign who gave the correct answer:

***This is because there is not any menu item related to those articles. Here is the info how to fix it:

The links are related to frontpage and not to articles because there is not any menu link to those articles and can not take the item id.
You can do the following.
Go in Menus / about joomla (or bottom menu). There click in new.
In "Menu Item Type" click select and chose "Category Blog".
Enter any menu title example QuickNews.
In Required Settings In "Choose a category" select  the category where are the articles with links on fronpage.
Click Save.
Best regards,
Olwebdesign***

Comment: Why didn't Olwebdesign post an answer here?